# BTC and BCH/BCC after fork

Tags: wallet

I have BTC in a paper wallet. Will that wallet also have BCH (a.k.a BCC) after the UAHF? Should I move the BTC to my blockchain.info wallet or another type of wallet to ensure I also own BCH after the fork?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a paper wallet, that means you have the public key and the private key of your BTC address.

This is sufficient to control both BTC (Bitcoin) and BCC (Bitcoin Cash) after the fork.

Comment: Hi, could you please advice here too please https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57899/get-bch-from-blockchain-info-after-fork Thanks