# Get BCH from blockchain.info after fork

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I had a fraction of BTC on *blockchain.info* before the 1st of August and I didn't touch them at all afterwards.

I **never got my private keys** (nor the 12 words) from my *blockchain.info* wallet (or if I did god knows where they are).

Question: if I try to get **my private keys (bip39) now will they be the same** so that I can get BCH following this guide http://www.coinpurveyor.com/how-to-claim-bitcoin-cash-from-blockchain-wallet/**?**

Thanks

*(PS. another useful guide: https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000013719-how-to-get-bitcoin-cash-from-many-wallet-software-services-with-coinomi)*

**UPDATE - THE ULTIMATE SOLUTION:**
https://www.coindesk.com/couldnt-claim-your-bitcoin-cash-btc-com-now-has-a-tool-for-that/

Comment: Note: if you instead kept your Bitcoin on Coinbase they stated that you'll get your BCH on 1st Jan 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Haven't looked at those guides in particular, but I was able to redeem BCH from a blockchain.info wallet by exporting my private keys following this guide: https://bl4nkcode.info/bitcoin/how_to_export_blockchain_wallet_private_key, and then importing them into Electron-Cash.

Answer (score 4):

Blockchain.info supports this now. Go to https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/settings/info Settings-general page and scroll to the Bitcoin Cash section. I was able to recover my amounts completely.

Comment: Yay! Awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

From August 22nd 2017, limited Bitcoin Cash support is coming to Blockchain.info over the next 8 weeks.

https://blog.blockchain.com/2017/08/22/bitcoin-cash-update/

Comment: Any update on this? I don't see any BCH support yet.. :(

Comment: @GaSacchi https://cointelegraph.com/news/blockchaininfo-releases-full-bitcoin-cash-support-users-receive-coins

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain.info now has BCH support. You can view your BCH balance under Settings -> General.

They have some information about this on the Blockchain Support Center:  [Bitcoin Cash (BCH)](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/sections/115001496703-Bitcoin-Cash-BCH-).

---

When logging into your Blockchain wallet you'll receive a notification like this:

> [image: Notification]

From here, if you navigate to Settings -> General and scroll to the bottom, you'll see the following:

> [image: Settings -> General]

Upon clicking 'Show Bitcoin Cash Balance' you'll be shown a dialog message telling you what Bitcoin Cash is, how it's different from Bitcoin and a few other bits of useful info. At the bottom of this dialog box is the following button:

> [image: See Bitcoin Cash Balance button]

Upon clicking this button you'll be shown another dialog box containing your BCH balance and its current value in your wallet's primary currency.

> [image: Bitcoin Cash Balance dialog]

Here you'll have the option to:

1. **Keep Bitcoin Cash** - Keep it in your Blockchain wallet, available to view at any time under Settings -> General.
2. **Exchange Bitcoin Cash** - Directly exchange it for Bitcoin or Ether.
3. **Send Bitcoin Cash** - Transfer it to a different Bitcoin Cash address.

Dismissing the dialog has the same affect as clicking "Keep Bitcoin Cash"; don't worry though, your Bitcoin Cash balance and both the "Exchange Bitcoin Cash" and "Send Bitcoin Cash" options are now permanently available under Settings -> General.

Comment: That "Show bitcoin cash balance" button is no longer under settings->general.