# Obtaining Bitcoin Cash generated at the fork in August 2017

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

I had Bitcoin in my ANX Wallet at the fork in August 2017 I transferred it to my Blockchain wallet in September. Is there any way I can obtain the Bitcoin cash generated at the fork?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like ANX will not give out the private key to your wallet, at least not now.

[ANX terms 16.5](https://anxpro.com/pages/terms):

> 16.5 In the event of a Fork, the value, function, and/or even the name of the Digital Asset you store on the Exchange may be materially
>   affected. In any such event, you agree that ANX may temporarily
>   suspend the service (with or without advance notice to you) in its
>   sole discretion and ANX may decide based on commercially reasonable
>   efforts either (a) configure or reconfigure its systems or (b) not to
>   support (or cease supporting) the branch derived from the forked
>   protocol. **In the instance of any private keys held and managed by ANX,
>   ANX does not convey ownership or any related rights associated with
>   the Users**. You acknowledge and agree that ANX assumes absolutely no
>   responsibilities whatsoever in respect of an unsupported branch of a
>   forked protocol.

[Bitcoin Cash fork happened August 1st, 2017](https://www.bitcoincash.org/#faq), only way for you to claim Bitcoin Cash is if you manage to persuade ANX to give it to you, or give you the private key.

However, you may be eligible for Bitcoin Gold if you had [Bitcoin in your Blockchain.info's wallet 2017-10-24](https://bitcoingold.org/faq/),if so then follow [this procedure](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57899/get-bch-from-blockchain-info-after-fork).