# blockchain.info: bitcoin cash from fork no longer visible

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I was previously able to see the bitcoin cash here:

[Get BCH from blockchain.info after fork](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57899/get-bch-from-blockchain-info-after-fork)

This no longer works and I'm unable to find it.

Anyone have insight?  I was in the process of moving the BCH the past week and the link has disappeared.